# Error converting Byte array to URL

Tags: java, jsp

I apologize for having opened a discussion like many others but i searched a lot in this site's discussions and i didn't found a solution that worked for me.
What i need to do is quite simple but i can't get out of it.
I have and jpg image stored in my DB ,in BLOB format ,and i want to get it back and create a tag IMG to show it.
After getting the blob by query i just convert it into byteArray.
Here come the problems.
If i write it in the response and access it in an other jsp I can see the image as well..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Image</title>
</head>

<body>

    <b>View | <a href="index.jsp">Upload</a></b><br/><br/>

    <%
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    %>
    <img src="Message.jsp" width="400px"/>

</body>
```

but if i try to create a tag IMG and setting the tag in the same page it wont be showed(as shown in the JSP code below).

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, pass);

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from contacts ");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()){
    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("photo");
    byte byteArray[] = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());


%>
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<%=byteArray %>" />
<%
  /*  response.setContentType("image/gif");
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    os.write(byteArray);
    os.flush();
    os.close();*/
}
```

(this don't show any img)

Comment: Well, you're supposed to encode the byte array to base 64, but you're not doing it. But anyway, the first solution is much better (except you shouldn't use a JSP to get the image from the DB and send it as a response, but a servlet. JSPs should not contain Java code).

Answer (score 0):

The img tag will make a separate server call to retrieve the image data. The src attribute should point to a servlet. The servlet should retrieve the image data and write it directly to the output stream.